# Accidentally drop of collection on shard of sharded MongoDB cluster

Tags: mongodb, restore, sharding

I have accidentally triggered a drop collection command on one replica set (primary-shard) of a MongoDB sharded cluster (no secondary shards). Unfortunately now I can not access the data of this shard anymore. On the machine the .wt files are still available and are not dropped. Also all the cache information of this collection is still available. The MongoDB is version 4.2.22.

Is there a way to restore the deleted collection on this shard again? Thanks in advance

Comment: Restore from backup. No backup - no mercy!

Comment: Do old chunks get moved from time to time, or can I be sure if I have backups of this shard at multiple intervals that I can easily restore those documents?  Backups are done when the database was in balanced mode

Comment: You need to try. In general backups (i.e snapshots) should be done while balancer is off (see [Schedule Backup Window for Sharded Clusters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/rapid/tutorial/schedule-backup-window-for-sharded-clusters/)) and `db.fsyncLock()` - see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/rapid/tutorial/backup-sharded-cluster-with-filesystem-snapshots/